# Find the equation of a circle with the help of given circular arcs

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

If the circular arcs $AC$ and $BC$ have centres at $B(-\alpha, 0) $and $A(\alpha, 0)$ respectively and the length of the arc BC is $8\pi$ . Find the equation of the circle which touches both arcs $AC$ and $BC$ and the line $AB$.

The major problem I am facing is that I am not able to figure out what kind of diagram will be made in this case i.e.  I am not able to determine how the diagram would look like.  Any help over the problem is appreciated.

Comment: Where did you receive this interesting question?

Comment: Are AC and BC equal?

Comment: I guess so. But I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this picture will help you to figure out better how to solve analytically the problem.

Hope it helps

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.